# Plugin with id 'com.github.spotbugs' not found

Tags: gradle, spotbugs

I'm configuring [SpotBugs plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.spotbugs) for a Gradle project for the first time.

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-gradle-plugin:1.6.6'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.github.spotbugs'
```

When running `gradle check` I'm getting error `Plugin with id 'com.github.spotbugs' not found.` What am I doing wrong?

Gradle version 5.0.

Comment: Have you also had a look at this? https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gradle.html

Comment: Your build script works for me with an otherwise empty Gradle 5.0 project (using a Gradle wrapper). The only change I’ve made to your build script is to add `apply plugin: 'java'` at the end to actually get the `check` task to test with. Do you have `caches/modules-2/files-2.1/gradle.plugin.com.github.spotbugs/spotbugs-gradle-plugin/1.6.6/` in you Gradle user home (typically `~/.gradle/`)? Otherwise there might have been an issue with your network connection to the Gradle plugins repository.

Comment: Why not use `plugins { id "com.github.spotbugs" version "1.6.6" }` DSL?

Comment: I'm having almost the same problem: The configuration you're using works for me - but I get the same error (Plugin with id 'com.github.spotbugs' not found) if I move it from build.gradle to another file (spotbugs.gradle) an apply in build.gradle with `apply from: 'spotbugs.gradle'`

Comment: I had the same problem, have a look at my solution https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/issues/1027#issuecomment-548588144